# Can survivors with the jump skill jump into/off towers in Zombicide: Black Plague - Wulfsburg Expansion?

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

The **Jump** skill states that:

> The Survivor can use this Skill once during each Activation. The Survivor spends one Action: He moves two Zones into a Zone to which he has Line of Sight. Movement related Skills (like +1 Zone per Move Action or Slippery) are ignored, but Movement penalties (like having Zombies in the starting
>   Zone) apply. Ignore everything in the intervening Zone.

An interesting tactic is to be able to jump into/out of towers. Is this legal?

Comment: sounds legal to me. Would be interesting to hear from someone who has tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use jump to move into/out of a tower, as the towers are surrounded by ramparts which specifically block movement.

From the [Wulfsburg rules](http://cmon.com/resources/ZBP_Wulfsburg_Rules_web.pdf) (page 5):

> Tower tiles feature both building and street Zones, bordered
>   by **ramparts** ....
>
> - Ramparts can’t be crossed but don’t block Lines of Sight.